# CRM 2011 Marketing List - Sending mail with Xperido

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have a marketing list consisting of selected contacts which we would like to send emails to.

Each contact has an Account Manager field (which is a system user).
Our marketing team would like to send all contacts in a list an email which should be addressed from the account manager (system user) email address.

We are using a document generation solution called Xperido. I am using a standard template to try accomplish this. Looking at the email settings configuration, you cannot specified an address from a secondary entity. The only address that you can use must be defined in the primary entity.

I have looked on the net and cannot find any example of this. Has anyone done this before or can suggest another product which is capable of this? Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have XperiDo version 3.2 you can do this by going to your XperiDo Management Console in CRM. First edit your dataset in that way that the linked Account manager (of the contacts) is fetched. Then select Templates and edit the template that you want to send out to the contacts. Go to More Settings and click the pencil next to E-mail settings
[image: Edit the e-mail settings]

Then you should see the following screen where you select in the From part: Data set field (this can be set as default by selecting the star on the right of the label) and then select the emailaddress field of the account manager.

[image: Account manager email address]

Then during the document generation itself select the template that you want to be mailed and on the Set Output Parameters tab you can select E-mail as delivery format and you can also choose to set there the right E-mail addresses as you can see in the following image.

[image: Set output parameter]

This method can also be used to set the To field of the e-mail section in XperiDo.